# nginx with expires on javascript files (dynamically generated by PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, expires-header

I have a problem with `expires` headers on javascript files which are generated by PHP..

The website has two types of javascript files. One part is static javascript files and one part is dynamically generated by PHP.

## conf without expires headers

Here no `expires` headers are added to the `.js` files (All files return `HTTP 200`)

```
location / {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/index.php;
}
```

## conf with expires headers

When adding a location for `.js` files then all dynamically generated files return `HTTP 404`

```
location / {
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/dyndev.dk/public/secure/index.php;
}

location ~ \.(js|css)$ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

How to handle both the static and dynamically generated `.js` files with `expires` headers?

All dynamically genereated javascript files are named `*-php.js`

## File structure

```
/var/www/public/index.php # All none-static file requests are pointed to index.php
/var/www/public/js/main.js # Static files
/var/www/js-dynamically_generated.php # This file is outside the public www, but is routed by PHP since the file doesn't exists inside the public /js
```

## PHP routing

```
www.example.com/ -> index.php
www.example.com/js -> static content
www.example.com/js/dynamically_generated-php.js -> js-dynamically_generated.php
```

Comment: if you create js with php why you don't add header with php functions?

Comment: Have updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For nginx, PHP is never Javascript. Nginx can't distinct between PHP which renders html and PHP which renders javascript (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So the way to go would be either to setup a seperate folder with PHP files which generate all JS (code is not tested!):

```
location ~ \normal_php/.php$ {
    include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/dyndev.dk/public/secure/index.php;
}

location ~ \js_php/.php$ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    include  /var/ini/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass  php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/dyndev.dk/public/secure/index.php;
}
```

...or send the header with PHP itself:

```
<?php
header('Expires: '. gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + (60 * 60))); // 1 hour
```

Comment: But how to I put `expires` headers on .js files? The problem is that when I add the location for .js files all dynamically genereated .js files return `404`. See my question in the second conf

Comment: Or are you saying that all php generated js files should be named `dynamic_js.php` instead of `dynamic_js-php.js`

Comment: Yes, the second comment. It would be even better to generate your assets via a build job, so you have a PHP script which generates static .js files.

Comment: Good idea.. Building static files would also be the fastest solution! :)